# InteliJ & javascript: is it possible for 'introduce variable' to be 'introduce const' instead?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

When we are inside awesome InteliJ in JavaScript and use Alt+Enter shortcut on some expression:

Lets say

```
cli.cliArgs();
```

We get a prompt such as ***Introduce local variable*** automating the creation of the following variable:

```
let cliArgs = cli.cliArgs();
```

Is it possible to have InteliJ introduce a 'const' value instead of variable values:

```
const cliArgs = cli.cliArgs();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can normally choose between `let`, `const` and `var` when introducing variable, and your choice is remembered (checked in 2020.1.4):

[image]

Comment: I was still on 2019 just downloaded 2020 thank you!